# How to disable display scaling on high DPI settings of an exe generated by Matlab compiler

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-compiler, highdpi

I don't like the Windows auto scaling on high DPI settings.  So I normally turn the scaling off by check the settings on Compatability of the exe properties.

I used Matlab compiler to generate an exe, but its Disable display scaling on high DPI settings is greyed.  When I run this exe, its window would be too big than normal.  How to disable the scaling so it's normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Control Panel: Display : Custome DPI Setting: Use Windows XP Style DPI scaling